# List used for a dynamic variable -- extra characters passing with the first and last string

Tags: python, list, dynamic

Having trouble using a list for a dynamic variable...the first and last items in the list are passing with additional characters.  I'm new to python so I'm hoping it's an easy fix...

```
symbols=['ALXN','AMAT','AMD','AMGN','AKAM']
print(symbols[0])
print(symbols[1])
print(symbols[2])
print(symbols[3])
print(symbols[4])

while 1: 
    
    day_bars_url = '{}/day?symbols={}&limit=6'.format(config.BARS_URL, symbols)
    r2 = requests.get(day_bars_url, headers=config.HEADERS)
    datadaily = r2.json()

    for symbol in datadaily:
        print("CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK: " + symbol)
```

Output looks like:

```
ALXN
AMAT
AMD 
AMGN
AKAM

CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  'AKAM']
CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  'AMAT'
CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  'AMD'
CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  'AMGN'
CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK: ['ALXN'
```

Want output to be:

```
ALXN
AMAT
AMD 
AMGN
AKAM

CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  AKAM
CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  AMAT
CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  AMD
CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  AMGN
CREATING DAY BAR CSV FOR STOCK:  ALXN
```

Comment: You are trying to pass a Python list to an API through querystring. We don't know which API that is, but you probably want to do something like `.format(config.BARS_URL, ",".join(symbols))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
By looking at your code it seems that you are calling:

```
day_bars_url = '{}/day?symbols={}&limit=6'.format(config.BARS_URL, symbols)
```

in such a way that your `symbols` parameter would look like

```
?symbols=['ALXN','AMAT','AMD','AMGN','AKAM']
```

implying that you get the parameters wrongly (`['ALXN'` for example).

**Solution:**
You can solve this by converting your list into a string before the usage:

```
symbols_text = ','.join(symbols)
day_bars_url = '{}/day?symbols={}&limit=6'.format(config.BARS_URL, symbols_text)
```

This way, `join()` will make a string with your symbols with a comma between them:

```
?symbols=ALXN,AMAT,AMD,AMGN,AKAM
```

Hope this answer was useful ;)

Comment: Happy to hear! You can then choose it as the answer to give support and close the topic ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the list directly in the line

```
day_bars_url = '{}/day?symbols={}&limit=6'.format(config.BARS_URL, symbols)
```

instead, you should pass in

```
day_bars_url = '{}/day?symbols={}&limit=6'.format(config.BARS_URL, ",".join(symbols))
```